# document.body.style.height = "100%";

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get a handle on the html tag to change the Background image but I'm running into: "TypeError: document.html is undefined" error.

My code:

```
    function init(){
        document.html.style.background ="url('175541_DSC_0291.JPG') no-repeat center center"; 
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        init();
    }
```

I lurked around for similar questions, closest I found was using the body tag instead. It works when I change the html object to body.

Additionally, I can easily set the html background to what I want in my CSS file, but I want to do it with JavaScript. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

to access to HTML tag, use::

```
document.documentElement
```

Answer (score 1):

`html` isn't a property of the `document` object. You need to use some other means to get it.

There are many.

e.g.

```
document.documentElement
document.body.parentNode
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
document.querySelector("html")
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0] was the very first one I tried and while it's working now, for some reason, it was not working when I first tried it.

Thanks for the first two though. Completely forgot about the parentNode.

Answer (score 1):

The `<html>` element can be referred through the document.documentElement property. To change the background, you can use:

```
document.documentElement.style.background = '';
```